# How to make a Widget clickable

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk

I have made a table using `GtkTable` and in that table I have attached widget in linux.

On each widget a video is displaying. Now I want to make all widgets click-able so I will be able to display clicked video in full screen mode.

What function should be used for making widget click-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what child widget you are using. Many widgets emits the signal `button-release-event` when the mouse clicks (press then release) on it. You can listen to the signal like this:

```
gboolean toggle_play(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
{
    // play or pause the video of the widget
    return TRUE; // or FALSE if you connected more than one handlers to this signal
}

g_signal_connect(widget, "button-release", G_CALLBACK (toggle_play), data);
```

where `widget` is your child widget to play videos, it will be passed as the first argument of `toggle_play`. `data` is additional data to be passed as the third argument of `toggle_play`, which can be simply `NULL` if not needed.

You may need to add `GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK` to the event mask of child widgets:

```
gtk_widget_add_events (widget, GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe widget `GtkEventBox` will help you.

Comment: That's a good choice unless the child widget captures mouse clicks (impossible to know without knowing details of the child widget).